ActiveMQ XML to Java Config
I converted my ActiveMQ XML config to Java Config but unfortunately getting this error
org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: direct://dispatcher.UpdateDomain. Exchange[ID-PF1RP6T9-1713855166866-0-1]    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:69) 

This is My XML Config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"        
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd   http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <camelContext id="camelContext"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <contextScan/>
    </camelContext>
    <bean class="fr.econsulting.gsc.core.task.TaskServiceBean">
        <property name="camelContext" ref="camelContext"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent" destroy-method="shutdown">
        <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <bean class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactoryBean">
                <property name="connectionFactory">
                    <bean class="org.apache.activemq.spring.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
                        <property name="brokerURL"                                   value="${activemq.brokerURL:tcp://gsc-services:61616?daemon=true}"/>
                        <property name="trustedPackages">
                            <list>
                                <value>fr.econsulting.gsc.core.task.message</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <!-- We have added preserve Message Qos header which will force us to send all header with messages itself -->
        <!--<property name="preserveMessageQos" value="true"/>-->
        <!-- These properties are being ignore because of preserveMessageQos, we are sending these values with message now-->
        <property name="acknowledgementModeName" value="CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE"/>
        <property name="deliveryMode" value="1"/>
        <property name="timeToLive" value="1260000"/>
    </bean>
    <bean name="messageRouteBuilder" class="fr.econsulting.gsc.core.task.camel.MessageRouteBuilder">
        <property name="additionalSerializableClass">
            <list>
                <value type="java.lang.Class">org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="fr.econsulting.gsc.core.task.config"/>
    <import resource="consumer-config.xml"/>
</beans>

This is the Changed Java Configuration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "fr.econsulting.gsc.core.task.config")
@Import(ConsumerConfig.class)
public class TaskConfig {

    @Value("${activemq.brokerURL:tcp://gsc-services:61616?daemon=true}")
    private String brokerURL;

    @Bean
    public CamelContext camelContext() throws Exception {
        return new DefaultCamelContext();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskServiceBean taskServiceBean(CamelContext camelContext) {
        return new TaskServiceBean(camelContext);
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory() throws Exception {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerURL);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("fr.econsulting.gsc.core.task.message");
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setTrustedPackages(list);
        return activeMQConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PooledConnectionFactoryBean pooledConnectionFactory() throws Exception {
        PooledConnectionFactoryBean pooledConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactoryBean();
        pooledConnectionFactory.setConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory());
        pooledConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return pooledConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public ActiveMQComponent activemq(PooledConnectionFactoryBean connectionFactory) throws Exception {
        ActiveMQComponent activeMQComponent = new ActiveMQComponent();
        activeMQComponent.setAutoStartup(true);
        activeMQComponent.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory.getConnectionFactory());

//        We have added preserve Message Qos header which will force us to send all header with messages itself
//        activeMQComponent.setPreserveMessageQos(true);
//        These properties are being ignore because of preserveMessageQos, we are sending these values with message now
        activeMQComponent.setAcknowledgementModeName("CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE");
        activeMQComponent.setDeliveryMode(1);
        activeMQComponent.setTimeToLive(1260000);

        return activeMQComponent;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageRouteBuilder messageRouteBuilder() {
        MessageRouteBuilder messageRouteBuilder = new MessageRouteBuilder();
        List<Class<? extends Serializable>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage.class);
        messageRouteBuilder.setAdditionalSerializableClass(list);
        return messageRouteBuilder;
    }
}

The Issue which I'm getting is related to the camel context bean
@Bean  
public CamelContext camelContext() throws Exception {  
       return new DefaultCamelContext();    
 }

Can anyone please help in converting the camel bean to java-config in correct manner.
